# I am creating a list of list in python with strings in it. How do I limit the list size so that a set of 3 gets appended to master list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, nested-loops

```
studentDetails = [["Sridhar", 10312, 94443], ["Aravindh", 103124, 99443]]
setDetails = []
count = 3


def myfunction(num):
    print("Welcome to the registration page")
    print("Please enter your name  : ")
    name = input()
    setDetails.append(name)
    print("Please enter your aadhaar number : ")
    aadhaar = input()
    setDetails.append(aadhaar)
    print("Please enter your phone number  : ")
    phoneNum = input()
    setDetails.append(phoneNum)


for i in range(0, count):
    for j in range(0,1):
        myfunction(i)
        studentDetails.append(setDetails)
        j+=1
    print(studentDetails)
    i+=1
```

Output:

```
Welcome to the registration page
Please enter your name  : 
Sid
Please enter your aadhaar number : 
123
Please enter your phone number  : 
13
[['Sridhar', 10312, 94443], ['Aravindh', 103124, 99443], ['Sid', '123', '13']]
Welcome to the registration page
Please enter your name  : 
Jon
Please enter your aadhaar number : 
3444
Please enter your phone number  : 
333
[['Sridhar', 10312, 94443], ['Aravindh', 103124, 99443], ['Sid', '123', '13', 'Jon', '3444', '333'], ['Sid', '123', '13', 'Jon', '3444', '333']]
```

Comment: define `setDetails = []` inside your function. That will solve your issue

Comment: @I have posted an answer for you. You can accept the answer if it satisfies your needs

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks .. worked for me

Answer (score 1):

```
studentDetails = [["Sridhar", 10312, 94443], ["Aravindh", 103124, 99443]]

count = 3


def myfunction():
    setDetails = [] #Define this inside your function
    print("Welcome to the registration page")
    print("Please enter your name  : ")
    name = input()
    setDetails.append(name)
    print("Please enter your aadhaar number : ")
    aadhaar = input()
    setDetails.append(aadhaar)
    print("Please enter your phone number  : ")
    phoneNum = input()
    setDetails.append(phoneNum)
    return setDetails


for i in range(0, count): studentDetails.append(myfunction())
print(studentDetails)
[['Sridhar', 10312, 94443], ['Aravindh', 103124, 99443], ['john', '123', '456'], ['madhir', '4532', '4567'], ['kijfr', '7345', '2346']]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
studentDetails = [["Sridhar", 10312, 94443], ["Aravindh", 103124, 99443]]
count = 3    

def myfunction(num):
    setDetails = []
    print("Welcome to the registration page")
    print("Please enter your name  : ")
    name = input()
    setDetails.append(name)
    print("Please enter your aadhaar number : ")
    aadhaar = input()
    setDetails.append(aadhaar)
    print("Please enter your phone number  : ")
    phoneNum = input()
    setDetails.append(phoneNum)
    return setDetails


for i in range(0, count):
    for j in range(0,1):
        setDetails = myfunction(i)
        studentDetails.append(setDetails)
        j+=1
    print(studentDetails)
    i+=1
```

Comment: The key problem is your code use the uncleared global variable (setDetails) always. Thus, i set the 'setDetails' as local variable of myfunction